# How to refactor a Haskell data type with fields into a tagged union of records?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, pattern-synonyms

In a large code base, I want to refactor a data type that has constructors with fields into a simple tagged union of records, mainly to better support `-Wincomplete-record-updates`.  It is important that I do not need to change any pattern matches over this data type, so I am trying to use record pattern synonyms.
Here is a cut-down version:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Werror=incomplete-patterns #-}

-- Consider some data type with fields:

data D'
  = A'
  | B' { b'Int :: Int, b'String :: String }

foo' :: D' -> String
foo' A'{} = "A"
foo' B'{b'String = x} = x

-- I'd like to factor out a record containing the fields
-- without changing foo'.

data D
  = A
  | BTag BRec

data BRec = BRec { _bInt :: Int, _bString :: String }

pattern B :: Int -> String -> D
pattern B{ bInt, bString } = BTag (BRec bInt bString)

foo :: D -> String
foo A{} = "A"
foo B{bString = x} = x

-- I get this error:
--     Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
--     In an equation for ‘foo’: Patterns of type ‘D’ not matched: BTag _
--    |
-- 28 | foo A{} = "A"
--    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Why do I get a pattern coverage error?  Am I using pattern synonyms correctly?  How to get the refactoring that i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [`COMPLETE` pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#complete-pragmas):

```
{-# COMPLETE A, B #-}
```

That can go anywhere in the file, but as an organizational thing it's useful to put it by the pattern definition. It's worth note that you can define multiple `COMPLETE` pragmas for the same type if there are multiple different sets that cover all possibilities. For instance, [Data.Sequence.Seq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq) has two:

```
{-# COMPLETE (:<|), Empty #-}
{-# COMPLETE (:|>), Empty #-}
```

This allows you plenty of flexibility in providing overlapping sets of synonyms that can be complete in different ways.

As for a justification of why it's necessary, [this article on the GHC wiki](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/pattern-synonyms/complete-sigs) makes a good argument:

> Pattern synonyms are a means of *abstraction*, if the exhaustiveness checker could look through a definition then the implementation of P would leak into error messages. We want users to be able to replace bona-fide data constructors with pattern synonyms without consumers noticing.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that argument. In particular, the behavior without a completeness pragma already violates that goal. Consider `module M (T(X,B)) where data T = A | B; pattern X = A`. Then, in another file, `import T; f B = ()` will give a warning that one of the missing patterns is `T.A`, a thing which we supposedly hid via abstraction. (And, indeed, I consider leaking this kind of thing into warnings to not really be a big deal; it is less helpful, but not "dangerous" to the abstraction.)